# Unexpected behavior when parsing JSON in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, next.js

After deploying to gcloud server, I would received an error of "unexpected token u in JSON at position 0". 
Which happens in

```
N=JSON.parse(window.__NEXT_DATA__.dataManager)
```

in /build/static/runtime/main.js.

And here is my next.config.js

```
test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
use: {
  loader: "url-loader",
}
```

Which I am not sure if that caused the issue.

I ended up deleting this part, and the website does run properly, however, other issues came out after failing to parse the __NEXT__DATA.dataManager.

I am hoping to know a proper and permanent way of solving this issue.

Comment: Could any one share any ideas?

Comment: Could any one share any possible ideas, I am still having trouble trying to solve it.